# force R plot through origin

Tags: r, plot

I have a simple plot in R:

```
roc = plot(RP.perf@alpha.values[[1]],RP.perf@x.values[[1]],type="l",ylim=c(0,1));
```

however would like to force the graph through the origin. is there anyway to do this? I can't find an option for this in the plot function.

Thanks.

Comment: `xlim=c(0,Max_X)`. Also, you don't need `;` at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the origin to the plot?

```
roc = plot(c(0, RP.perf@alpha.values[[1]] ),
           c(0, RP.perf@x.values[[1]] ) ,type="l",ylim=c(0,1));
```

Comment: It creates a point at (0,0), so it's probably not good for a final draft. Even so, this is a great trick for Q&D exploratory data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 6)
y <- c(4, 6, 8)
xlim <- c(0, 10)
ylim <- c(0, 10)

plot(x, y, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```